# Can you emit warnings in HLSL?

Tags: directx, hlsl

Is it possible to emit warnings in HLSL? If so, how?
I know there's `#error` keyword in HLSL to emit errors like:

```cpp
#ifndef PI
#error "PI is not defined"
#endif
```

But I want to do something like this:

```cpp
#if !defined(MAX_SIZE)
#warning "Max size is not defined, defaulting to 1024"
#define MAX_SIZE 1024
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific macro for warning.

However, something like that can work for you.

```
#pragma message "Warning: Max size is not defined, defaulting to 1024"
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/message-pragma-directive--directx-hlsl-).